# How do I make an image in the navigation bar bigger?

Tags: clojure, bulma, hiccup

I'm making a landing page based on the one from [Clojure Bridge](https://github.com/ClojureBridgeLondon/clojurebridge-landing-page).

I made the navigation bar bigger using `py-3` and added a logo. But the logo that's in the navigation bar is still tiny. It takes up a fraction of the space it could. How do I make it bigger?

```
(defn navigation-top
  []
  ;; Navigation bar (responsive)
  [:nav {:class      "navbar is-fixed-top is-white has-shadow py-3"
         :role       "navigation"
         :aria-label "main navigation"}
   [:div {:class "container"}
    [:div {:class "navbar-brand"}
     [:a {:class "navbar-item"
          :href  "/"}
      [:img {:src "img/logo.png"}]]
     [:span {:class       "navbar-burger burger"
             :data-target "navbarClojureBridge"}
      ;; Empty spans needed for navbar burger
      [:span] [:span] [:span]]]
    [:div {:id    "navbarClojureBridge"
           :class "navbar-menu"}
     [:div {:class "navbar-end"}
      [:a {:class "navbar-item"
           :href  "/contact"
           :style {:font-weight "bold"}} "Contact"]]]]])
```

Edit: I think with the navbar the problem is that there is padding around the image, but I don't know how to get rid of it. I'm using bulma, so would I have to go digging through the bulma file?

Comment: Yeah, look at the Bulma docs.  Then modify the Hiccup to match what you'd want the class to be.